# I need to use User Defined Functions to create lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing code that involves user defines functions, something which I'm new at.

```
from statistics import *
years = [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
woodDeaths = [19.6, 10.4 ,10.5 ,13.8, 23.1, 19.6, 26.7, 27.8, 53.7]

mcdowellDeaths = [102.2, 103.3, 108.5, 119.7, 70.3, 105.4, 107.6, 141.2, 73.1]

mercerDeaths = [46.9, 22.5, 54.6, 81.6, 59.2, 40.3, 76.1, 62.1, 74.4]

raleighDeaths = [24.2, 15.2, 57.1, 75.8, 73.4, 46.9, 49.8, 80, 58.7]

def get_average(raw_data):
    raw_data = sum(raw_data) / len(raw_data)
    return raw_data
def calculate_z_scores(raw_data):
    z_scores = []
    for i in raw_data:
        z_score = i - (sum(raw_data) / len(raw_data)) / raw_data.stdev
    append.z_scores(z_score)
    return z_scores
def print_stats(deaths_data, county):
    get_average(deaths_data)
    print (f" In {county} the average deaths was {deaths_data}")
    calculate_z_scores(deaths_data)
    z_scores = calculate_z_scores
    for i in years:
        print (f" In {years}, the z-score is: {z_score}")
def main():
    print_stats (woodDeaths, "Wood County")
    print_stats (mcdowellDeaths, "McDowell County")
    print_stats (mercerDeaths, "Mercer County")
    print_stats (raleighDeaths, "Raleigh County")
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

But whenever I try to run the code, I get one error, fix it, then get another error. Could anyone help me with how to fix this?
[The Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH83x.png)

```
In Wood County the average deaths was [19.6, 10.4, 10.5, 13.8, 23.1, 19.6, 26.7, 27.8, 53.7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brenn\Documents\python\bouillion_brennan_hw3_ocp.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\brenn\Documents\python\bouillion_brennan_hw3_ocp.py", line 28, in main
    print_stats (woodDeaths, "Wood County")
  File "C:\Users\brenn\Documents\python\bouillion_brennan_hw3_ocp.py", line 23, in print_stats
    calculate_z_scores(deaths_data)
  File "C:\Users\brenn\Documents\python\bouillion_brennan_hw3_ocp.py", line 17, in calculate_z_scores
    z_score = i - (sum(raw_data) / len(raw_data)) / raw_data.stdev
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'stdev'
```

This is the error i get now

Comment: "But whenever I try to run the code, I get one error, fix it, then get another error. " You need to provide a much more detailed problem specification than that. Please see [ask]. Fundamentally, though, you need to understand how functions work. This probably would be better for you to look at a Python tutorial so you even know where to begin. Otherwise, please ask a much more constrained question.

Comment: Yes, but not in the way you are asking. Please post the error output here as text. We will help you work through one error at a time. Show your fixes and explain what errors they cause too.

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: Well, `raw_data` is a `list` object (part of Python standard library) which doesn't have a `stdev` member. Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) which contain a usage example for `stdev()`

Comment: You never responded to anything in the previous question you asked about this function. You've simply made an even *broader* question that is more poorly constrained.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There were a lot of errors, but here is a cleaned up version.

```
from statistics import *
years = [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016]
woodDeaths = [19.6, 10.4 ,10.5 ,13.8, 23.1, 19.6, 26.7, 27.8, 53.7]

mcdowellDeaths = [102.2, 103.3, 108.5, 119.7, 70.3, 105.4, 107.6, 141.2, 73.1]

mercerDeaths = [46.9, 22.5, 54.6, 81.6, 59.2, 40.3, 76.1, 62.1, 74.4]

raleighDeaths = [24.2, 15.2, 57.1, 75.8, 73.4, 46.9, 49.8, 80, 58.7]

def get_average(raw_data):
    raw_data = sum(raw_data) / len(raw_data)
    return raw_data

def calculate_z_scores(raw_data):
    z_scores = []
    for i in raw_data:
        z_score = (i - (sum(raw_data) / len(raw_data))) / stdev(raw_data)
        z_scores.append(z_score)
    return z_scores

def print_stats(deaths_data, county):
    get_average(deaths_data)
    print (f" In {county} the average deaths was {get_average(deaths_data):0.0f}")
    calculate_z_scores(deaths_data)
    z_score = calculate_z_scores(deaths_data)
    for year,z_score in zip(years,z_score):
        print (f" In {year}, the z-score is: {z_score:0.4f}")

def main():
    print_stats (woodDeaths, "Wood County")
    print_stats (mcdowellDeaths, "McDowell County")
    print_stats (mercerDeaths, "Mercer County")
    print_stats (raleighDeaths, "Raleigh County")
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Your initial error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'stdev'` was because you were trying to call the attribute stdev of your list, but this attribute does not exist. However, you can call the method `stdev` on a list since you imported the statistics module.

Like I said, there were a lot of errors in the code. I could enumerate them, but a bit of time. If you have any questions, let me know.

As a word of advice for implementing big blocks of code: make sure each function or block of code works before implementing it into your program.

Output:

```
 In Wood County the average deaths was 23
 In 2008, the z-score is: -0.2418
 In 2009, the z-score is: -0.9368
 In 2010, the z-score is: -0.9292
 In 2011, the z-score is: -0.6799
 In 2012, the z-score is: 0.0227
 In 2013, the z-score is: -0.2418
 In 2014, the z-score is: 0.2946
 In 2015, the z-score is: 0.3777
 In 2016, the z-score is: 2.3345
 In McDowell County the average deaths was 103
 In 2008, the z-score is: -0.0590
 In 2009, the z-score is: -0.0082
 In 2010, the z-score is: 0.2317
 In 2011, the z-score is: 0.7485
 In 2012, the z-score is: -1.5309
 In 2013, the z-score is: 0.0887
 In 2014, the z-score is: 0.1902
 In 2015, the z-score is: 1.7406
 In 2016, the z-score is: -1.4017
 In Mercer County the average deaths was 58
 In 2008, the z-score is: -0.5600
 In 2009, the z-score is: -1.8465
 In 2010, the z-score is: -0.1541
 In 2011, the z-score is: 1.2694
 In 2012, the z-score is: 0.0885
 In 2013, the z-score is: -0.9080
 In 2014, the z-score is: 0.9795
 In 2015, the z-score is: 0.2414
 In 2016, the z-score is: 0.8898
 In Raleigh County the average deaths was 53
 In 2008, the z-score is: -1.3054
 In 2009, the z-score is: -1.7070
 In 2010, the z-score is: 0.1626
 In 2011, the z-score is: 0.9970
 In 2012, the z-score is: 0.8899
 In 2013, the z-score is: -0.2925
 In 2014, the z-score is: -0.1631
 In 2015, the z-score is: 1.1844
 In 2016, the z-score is: 0.2340
```

Comment: Please do not encourage people to come here and dump their homework expecting corrections. Homework questions can be on-topic, but this one is not.

Comment: I figured the coder had the right ideas, but just need a bit of a cleanup. The changes I proposed were not major, most were syntactic changes.